# How to fix my View Query to get result exactly as I want?

Tags: sql-server, view

I've got an issue in MSSQL View Query to get result as I want. The query I have make for select data from multiple Tables query is this below:

```
SELECT dbo.Customer.Code, dbo.Customer.Name, dbo.Customer.Mobile, dbo.Customer.Email, dbo.Customer.Adults, dbo.Customer.Kids, dbo.Customer.Days, dbo.Customer.PackageId, 
                      dbo.Packages.PackagesName, dbo.Customer.ArrivalCityId, ArrivalCity.Citys AS ArrivalCity, dbo.Customer.ArrivalTime, dbo.Customer.ArrivalDate, dbo.Customer.DepartureCityId, 
                      DepartureCity.Citys AS DepartureCity, dbo.Customer.DepartureTime, dbo.Customer.DepartureDate, dbo.Customer.GST, dbo.Customer.Discount, dbo.Customer.Profit, dbo.Customer.Advance, 
                      dbo.Customer.TotalPayment, dbo.ProvideHotel.CityId, HotelCity.Citys AS HotelCity, dbo.ProvideHotel.HotelId, dbo.Hotel.Hotels, dbo.ProvideHotel.RoomTypeId, 
                      HotelCategory.Name AS HotelCategory, dbo.ProvideTransport.PickCityId, PickCity.Citys AS PickCity, dbo.ProvideTransport.DropCityId, DropCity.Citys AS DropCity, dbo.ProvideTransport.TransportId, 
                      dbo.Transport.Transports, dbo.TourProgramme.DayId, DayCategory.Name AS NoOfDays, dbo.TourProgramme.FromCityId, FromCity.Citys AS FromCity, dbo.TourProgramme.ToCityId, 
                      ToCity.Citys AS ToCity, dbo.Customer.Id, dbo.TourProgramme.CustomerId, dbo.TourProgramme.Programme
FROM  dbo.Customer    INNER JOIN 
                      dbo.Packages ON dbo.Customer.PackageId = dbo.Packages.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.City AS ArrivalCity ON dbo.Customer.ArrivalCityId = ArrivalCity.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.City AS DepartureCity ON dbo.Customer.DepartureCityId = DepartureCity.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ProvideHotel ON dbo.Customer.Id = dbo.ProvideHotel.CustomerId INNER JOIN
                      dbo.City AS HotelCity ON dbo.ProvideHotel.CityId = HotelCity.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Hotel ON dbo.ProvideHotel.HotelId = dbo.Hotel.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Category AS HotelCategory ON dbo.ProvideHotel.RoomTypeId = HotelCategory.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ProvideTransport ON dbo.Customer.Id = dbo.ProvideTransport.CustomerId INNER JOIN
                      dbo.City AS PickCity ON dbo.ProvideTransport.PickCityId = PickCity.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.City AS DropCity ON dbo.ProvideTransport.DropCityId = DropCity.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Transport ON dbo.ProvideTransport.TransportId = dbo.Transport.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.TourProgramme ON dbo.Customer.Id = dbo.TourProgramme.CustomerId AND dbo.Packages.Id = dbo.TourProgramme.PackagesId INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Category AS DayCategory ON dbo.TourProgramme.DayId = DayCategory.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.City AS FromCity ON dbo.TourProgramme.FromCityId = FromCity.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.City AS ToCity ON dbo.TourProgramme.ToCityId = ToCity.Id Where dbo.Customer.Id = '2'
```

and it give me result like this in image
[Query give result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkdDW.png)
I don't want like this, I want which value us getting again and again that should be stop and give single value under tour programme which I have make with red circle.

Answer (score 0):

I hope to have correctly understood: use DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.Customer.Code, dbo.Customer.Name, dbo.Customer.Mobile, dbo.Customer.Email, dbo.Customer.Adults, dbo.Customer.Kids, dbo.Customer.Days, dbo.Customer.PackageId, 
                      dbo.Packages.PackagesName, dbo.Customer.ArrivalCityId, ArrivalCity.Citys AS ArrivalCity, dbo.Customer.ArrivalTime, dbo.Customer.ArrivalDate, dbo.Customer.DepartureCityId, 
                      DepartureCity.Citys AS DepartureCity, dbo.Customer.DepartureTime, dbo.Customer.DepartureDate, dbo.Customer.GST, dbo.Customer.Discount, dbo.Customer.Profit, dbo.Customer.Advance, 
                      dbo.Customer.TotalPayment, dbo.ProvideHotel.CityId, HotelCity.Citys AS HotelCity, dbo.ProvideHotel.HotelId, dbo.Hotel.Hotels, dbo.ProvideHotel.RoomTypeId, 
                      HotelCategory.Name AS HotelCategory, dbo.ProvideTransport.PickCityId, PickCity.Citys AS PickCity, dbo.ProvideTransport.DropCityId, DropCity.Citys AS DropCity, dbo.ProvideTransport.TransportId, 
                      dbo.Transport.Transports, dbo.TourProgramme.DayId, DayCategory.Name AS NoOfDays, dbo.TourProgramme.FromCityId, FromCity.Citys AS FromCity, dbo.TourProgramme.ToCityId, 
                      ToCity.Citys AS ToCity, dbo.Customer.Id, dbo.TourProgramme.CustomerId, dbo.TourProgramme.Programme
FROM  dbo.Customer    INNER JOIN 
                      dbo.Packages ON dbo.Customer.PackageId = dbo.Packages.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.City AS ArrivalCity ON dbo.Customer.ArrivalCityId = ArrivalCity.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.City AS DepartureCity ON dbo.Customer.DepartureCityId = DepartureCity.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ProvideHotel ON dbo.Customer.Id = dbo.ProvideHotel.CustomerId INNER JOIN
                      dbo.City AS HotelCity ON dbo.ProvideHotel.CityId = HotelCity.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Hotel ON dbo.ProvideHotel.HotelId = dbo.Hotel.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Category AS HotelCategory ON dbo.ProvideHotel.RoomTypeId = HotelCategory.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ProvideTransport ON dbo.Customer.Id = dbo.ProvideTransport.CustomerId INNER JOIN
                      dbo.City AS PickCity ON dbo.ProvideTransport.PickCityId = PickCity.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.City AS DropCity ON dbo.ProvideTransport.DropCityId = DropCity.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Transport ON dbo.ProvideTransport.TransportId = dbo.Transport.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.TourProgramme ON dbo.Customer.Id = dbo.TourProgramme.CustomerId AND dbo.Packages.Id = dbo.TourProgramme.PackagesId INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Category AS DayCategory ON dbo.TourProgramme.DayId = DayCategory.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.City AS FromCity ON dbo.TourProgramme.FromCityId = FromCity.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.City AS ToCity ON dbo.TourProgramme.ToCityId = ToCity.Id Where dbo.Customer.Id = '2'
```

Comment: its still showing value like that in ProvideTransport have 4 value in one customer and some have 1 value in it ans some have 2